# How to assign certain themes to certain to Content Types?

Tags: theming, nodes

I am trying to assign certain themes to certain content types. Is there any way to do this in the admin configurations? I don't particularly want to use a module or modify php code for this.

Comment: There is no way to do this with core functionality. You must extend Drupal to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said that you don't want to use a module, but [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) does exactly what you need. There is no Drupal core functionality that provides this functionality.

Comment: Context module does this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Content Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_theme) module.

The Content Theme module is a simple and easy module to use which allows to use different themes than the site default on content creating, editing, and viewing pages.

**Features**

Assign a theme to all content. (This overrides the system default theme)

Assign a theme to a content type. (This overrides content wide themes and system default)

Assign a theme to a content node. (This overrides content type themes, content wide themes, and system default)

Allow to use different themes on content creating/editing pages than on viewing pages.

Fine-grained permission control.

Drupal novice friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If the views and panels modules are installed, you can create a view, hide or show the fields you want to show, create a panel to display the view.